# How to convert UTC to local time while reading XML using OpenXML?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, utc, sql-server-openxml

Data is stored as XML (Sample):-

```
<root>
    <data>
        <checked>true</checked>
        <datetimestamp>2016-10-18T08:11:12-06:00</datetimestamp>
    </data>
    <data>
        <checked>true</checked>
        <datetimestamp>2016-10-18T08:13:20-06:00</datetimestamp>
    </data>
</root>
```

I am reading data using OpenXML:-

```
DECLARE @XData XML
DECLARE @doc INT

DECLARE @TempXML TABLE
(
    checked BIT,
    datetimestamp DATETIME,
)  

SELECT @XData = Data FROM Table1 WHERE ID = @ItemId

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @doc OUTPUT, @XData

INSERT INTO @TempXML(checked,datetimestamp)  
    SELECT * FROM OPENXML (@doc, '/root/data',1)
    WITH (
    checked BIT 'checked',
    DateTimeStamp DATETIME 'datetimestamp',
    )
```

DateTime is stored as UTC in XML. In above SP I am reading xml data using openXML and storing data in a temp table. 
I need to convert UTC datetime into local time while inserting. How can I do that. 
Following line of code convert UTC to local time zone perfectly **but could not figure out how to use it with Openxml**:-

```
SELECT DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), MyTable.UtcColumn) 
       AS ColumnInLocalTime
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just specify your columns in your `insert` statement?

```
INSERT INTO @TempXML(checked,datetimestamp)
    SELECT checked
            ,DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), datetimestamp) as datetimestamp
    FROM OPENXML (@doc, '/root/data',1)
    WITH (
    checked BIT 'checked',
    DateTimeStamp DATETIME 'datetimestamp'
    )
```